# Multiprocessing SQL queries to dataframe with python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, multiprocessing

I'm adapting a python script that I found as an answer to a similar question (56400556). The script works but currently the SQL results are being stored in a list, while I'm looking to export this to a dataframe (or second option to csvs).

Is there a way to run SQL queries in parallel (as each query takes about 10 minutes) and have this data stored in a dataframe. It can either be one dataframe with the result of all queries or one dataframe per query, it doesn't matter

Secondary issue would be to avoid listing all the SQL queries as only one paramenter change but have one SQL query and a list of parameters to input (e.g.: 'UK','IT','US', etc)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import os

query_load = [("SELECT * FROM customer_table WHERE country ='UK' "),
             ("SELECT * FROM customer_table  WHERE country ='IT' ")]

db_conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="hostname",
    database="databasename",
    user="username",
    password="password")

def read_sql(query):
    return pd.read_sql(query, db_conn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        data_load =  p.map(read_sql, query_load)
    print(data_load)
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you add an index on `country`?

Comment: Yes I added indexs to the SQL table but that does not speed up the query

Comment: How many rows are there in the database? Millions?